# formula sequence problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

Excuse me in advance if I'm not clear, my english is not very good.
I want to find a formula from a tuning system for a synth.

here is the concept, it's a sort of "just intonation" tuning system.

Musical tuning systems based on 33 hertz

1 tone equal temperament (this one is super simple x = 33. * pow(2, x) )

33
66
132
264
528
1056
2112
4224
8448
16896

But when we try with two notes per octave, I don't understand how to find the formula. Here are the frequencies.

2 tone equal temperament

33  49.5
66  99
132 198
264 396
528 792
1056    1584
2112    3168
4224    6336
8448    12672
16896

Can you help me please?

Thank you very much for your help.

Guillaume

Answer (score 1):

Another method: Middle note is $3/2$ of the octave.

In the case that we want to modify the middle note so that it's $3/2$ of the octave instead of $\sqrt{2}$, the story gets a little bit complicated. The ratios of the consequent notes will alternate between $3/2$ and $4/3$. The product $\frac{3}{2} \times \frac{4}{3} = 2$, so this should indeed be the case. There should be several ways of going about this, but one is the recursive relation
$$
f_n = \frac{7-(-1)^n}{5-(-1)^n} f_{n-1} \qquad \text{with} \qquad f_0=33
$$
I obtained this by asking myself: How can I generate a sequence that alternates between the values $3/2$ and $4/3$ ? First I must generate a sequence that alternates between 3 and 4, and I came up with $\frac{7}{2} - \frac{(-1)^n}{2}$. A similar approach was used to generate a sequence that alternates between 2 and 3, namely $\frac{5}{2} - \frac{(-1)^n}{2}$. I divided those and obtained $\frac{7-(-1)^n}{5-(-1)^n}$. So there, there's one expression that results in the given sequence. Does this answer your question?

Comment: wow thank you for that, th'ats interesting. I have the feeling all of that besomes complex now. Maybe what I want is not really possible?

Comment: Why do you think it's not possible? I gave you a formula that you can use. Is there still something that you need help with?

Comment: yes you're right but then if I want 3, 4 or 5 note per octave? the formula becomes complex no?

Comment: Well it depends on what ratios you want to replace. It's easy to generate a fixed-ratio system, but in this case you wanted a "custom" ratio. So, as I said, it depends on what you require and want. I don't know what you would want from a 3 or 4 note system. What would their ratios be? Also, if you're just making this for some program, it might be easier to just list all the frequencies that you need. I mean, it doesn't take longer than a few minutes ...

Comment: exactly I have all the frequencies until 16 note per octave. I was just thinking, maybe there is an elegant way with a formula to calculate that :)

Comment: Also, feel free to upvote or mark any of my workings, if you feel like they have helped you or provided the soluton to the question.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_{2n-1}=\frac{33}{2}(2^{n})$$
Which is the same as the first sequence but
$$a_{2n}=a_{2n-1}+\frac{33}{4}(2^{n})$$
$$a_{2n}=\frac{99}{4}(2^n)$$

Answer (score 0):

An octave means a ratio of two, so 66 is an octave above 33. But now we want to put a note in between 33 and 66 so that it's "equally far" from 33 and 66. And by "equally far", I mean in the logarithmic sense. So really I mean that the ratio between the middle note and the lower note is the same as the ratio of the higher note and the lower note. So we want a middle note with a frequency $m$ (for middle) so that
$$
\frac{m}{33} = \frac{66}{m}
$$
With a bit of algebra, we get $m^2 = 66\times 33 = 2\times 33^2 \Rightarrow m = \sqrt{2} \times 33$. Therefore, for a two-notes-per-octave system,our "half-step" is equal to a ratio of $\sqrt{2}\approx 1.4142$. Therefore, the series is
$$
f_n = 33\times \sqrt{2}^n = 33 \times 2^{n/2}
$$
where $f_n$ is the $n$th frequency. $f_0 = 33$, $f_1 \approx 44.669$, $f_2 = 66$, $f_3\approx 94.338$ etc.

With several notes per octave, it's easy to see how to expand this idea. You just need to divide the exponent by the number of notes you want per octave.

Comment: Hey thank you very much for your response, but I think there is a problem here.
If I take the 3 first numbers in the two notes per octave I have 33, 49.5, 66. If I divides them by 33, I have 1 1.5 2 and this 1.5 is the middle of 1 and 2. But 1.5 is not equal to √2. you follow me? so with your formula I have   33, 46.66, 66. It's not the same. Or maybe I didn't understood something?

Comment: As I understand, the definition of equal temperament is that the ratio of subsequent frequencies is a constant. But if we look at the first three values in the list you gave, $49.5/33= 1.5$ and $66/49.5\approx 1.333$ so it's not exactly equal ratios. The ratio in the list alternates between $\frac{3}{2}$ and $\frac{4}{3}$. My solution shows a system where the ratio is always the same, equal to $\sqrt{2}$. So it's a question of what your requirements are and what you want to do ...

Comment: @GuillaumeCouette You are describing equal *intervals* $66-49.5 = 49.5 - 33$. Matti P is describing equal equal *ratios* $\frac{66}{44.669}=\frac{44.669}{33}$. An equal temperament system of musical tuning is based on equal ratios, not equal intervals.

Comment: okay, now I understand. So what I want to do is not create an equal temperament system but an equal interval.  This is why I was sayng a "just intonation" system where the ratio of the middle note of an octave is 3/2.